# How to create Cladogram graphs with Vega?

Tags: vega

Is there a way to create a [Cladogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cladogram) chart with Vega syntax?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy-pasting your own answer from Phabricator, if other people find this question:

Jeff Heer gave some examples of vega specs for [radial trees](https://github.com/vega/vega/pull/425#issuecomment-155249622), [cartesian trees](https://github.com/vega/vega/pull/425#issuecomment-155249696), and [dendograms](https://github.com/vega/vega/pull/425#issuecomment-155317689).